# Loading conversation messages in chat app with Firestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, chat

When building a chat app with React Native and Redux, with Firestore for backend, what is the best way to load messages for a particular conversation?

I display 8 chat entries in the beginning, and when I click at one I will see the chat screen with 20 latest messages. Is it a good idea to implement real time listeners to each chat's (not all chats, just those that are displayed, because pagination is used) 20 latest messages from each one's `messages` collection and have them ready beforehand?

Or is it a better idea to load the messages when a particular chat's messages screen is being opened.

I understand that as user experience the first option is better because there is no latency in showing the first 20 messages for a chat, but doesn't it consume a lot of data that might never be necessary, because out of the 8 chats, the user might interact with only 2 or 3.

Is there any better way besides these two?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If is a good idea or not, it's up to you to decide according to what kind of chat app you want to create. It's always a trade between the latency that you were talking about and the amount of data that you get and that might be or might not be seen by the user. Furthermore, if you say you have 8 chat rooms with 20 messages, it means that by default, when the user opens your chat app, Firestore will charge you with 8*20=**160** read operations, even if the user enters a chat room or not and I think is not such a good idea. If you have a few users, there won't be a problem but if your app grows, you might think again about this. In Firestore, everything is about the number of reads and writes according to their [pricing plan](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing).

Comment: Hi Romin! Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should think of upgrading your UX by giving the app offline capabilities instead of loading unnecessary data all at one. You should fetch data for a concerned chat and make your app memorize the latest 10-20 messages and you can always sync your data. You might want to consider [Realm](https://realm.io/products/realm-database) or [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html).

Also for better UX for the chats screen where the chats will be shown, you should consider making your `chat-list` node to accomodate last message and timestamp in each chat so that you wont have to nest the query for each chat item for just one screen rendering.